# Doubts in running an Rcpp example

Tags: rcpp

I'm trying to reproduce the examples of "Seamless R and C++ Integration with Rcpp" book, but some codes are not running. Specifically, it is on chapter 5, Section 5.2.3 and the code follows above:

```
#ifndef _mypackage_RCPP_HELLO_WORLD_H
#define _mypackage_RCPP_HELLO_WORLD_H

    ￼￼￼#include <Rcpp.h>
    ￼￼/*
       * note : RcppExport is an alias to 'extern "C"' defined by Rcpp.
       ￼￼￼*
       * It gives C calling convention to the rcpp_hello_world
       * function so that it can be called from .Call in R. 
       * Otherwise, the C++ compiler mangles the
       * name of the functioand .Call can’t find it.
       * It is only useful to use RcppExport when the function
       * is intended to be called by .Call. See the thread
       * http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.rcpp/649/focus=672
       * on Rcpp-devel for a misuse of RcppExport 19 
    */


    RcppExport SEXP rcpp_hello_world();

    ￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼#endif
```

and the next is

```
#include "rcpp_hello_world.h"

SEXP rcpp_hello_world() {
    using namespace Rcpp;

    CharacterVector x = CharacterVector::create( "foo", "bar" )  ;
    NumericVector y   = NumericVector::create( 0.0, 1.0 ) ;
    List z            = List::create( x, y ) ;

    return z ;
}
```

The error showed by R is

```
Error in .Call("rcpp_hello_world", PACKAGE = "mypackage") : 
  "rcpp_hello_world" not available for .Call() for package "mypackage"
```

Have anyone faced a problem like this?

Thanks in advance!

---

When I try to tip

```
R CMD check mypackage_1.0.tar.gz
```

I got an error like this

```
* using log directory ‘/Users/Marcos/Downloads/mypackage.Rcheck’
* using R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
* using platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)
* using session charset: UTF-8
* checking for file ‘mypackage/DESCRIPTION’ ... OK
* checking extension type ... Package
* this is package ‘mypackage’ version ‘1.0’
* checking package namespace information ... OK
* checking package dependencies ... OK
* checking if this is a source package ... OK
* checking if there is a namespace ... OK
* checking for executable files ... OK
* checking for hidden files and directories ... OK
* checking for portable file names ... OK
* checking for sufficient/correct file permissions ... OK
* checking whether package ‘mypackage’ can be installed ... ERROR
    Installation failed.
See ‘/Users/Marcos/Downloads/mypackage.Rcheck/00install.out’ for details.
```

In the file 00install.out, the first error is

```
* installing *source* package ‘mypackage’ ...
** libs
llvm-g++-4.2 -arch x86_64 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include"   -fPIC  -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:28,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:27,
                 from RcppExports.cpp:4:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/platform/compiler.h:93:17: error: cmath: No such file or directory
```

And then, I just got error messages.

Answer (score 1):

This example (and chapter) discusses how to build (and load) an entire package, here called `mypackage`.

Did you actually create, compile and load `mypackage`?

This works, as we do this each and every time the unit tests run.

*Edit:*  Here is a full log for you

```
R> library(Rcpp)
R> Rcpp.package.skeleton("mypackage")   ## page 66, Section 5.2.1
Creating directories ...
Creating DESCRIPTION ...
Creating NAMESPACE ...
Creating Read-and-delete-me ...
Saving functions and data ...
Making help files ...
Done.
Further steps are described in './mypackage/Read-and-delete-me'.

Adding Rcpp settings
 >> added Depends: Rcpp
 >> added LinkingTo: Rcpp
 >> added useDynLib directive to NAMESPACE
 >> added Makevars file with Rcpp settings
 >> added Makevars.win file with Rcpp settings
 >> added example src file using Rcpp attributes
 >> compiled Rcpp attributes
 >> added Rd file for rcpp_hello_world
R>
```

We can now build the tarball:

```
R> system("R CMD build mypackage")
* checking for file 'mypackage/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* preparing 'mypackage':
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* cleaning src
* checking for LF line-endings in source and make files
* checking for empty or unneeded directories
* building 'mypackage_1.0.tar.gz'

R>
```

then we can install it:  (and I am doing that on a Windows machine for a change)

```
R> system("R CMD INSTALL mypackage_1.0.tar.gz")
* installing to library 'c:/opt/R-library'
* installing *source* package 'mypackage' ...
** libs

*** arch - i386
g++ -m32 -I"c:/opt/R-CURR~1/include" -DNDEBUG    -I"c:/opt/R-library/Rcpp/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
g++ -m32 -I"c:/opt/R-CURR~1/include" -DNDEBUG    -I"c:/opt/R-library/Rcpp/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c rcpp_hello_world.cpp -o rcpp_hello_world.o
g++ -m32 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o mypackage.dll tmp.def RcppExports.o rcpp_hello_world.o c:/opt/R-library/Rcpp/lib/i386/libRcpp.a -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib/i386 -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib -Lc:/opt/R-CURR~1/bin/i386 -lR
installing to c:/opt/R-library/mypackage/libs/i386

*** arch - x64
g++ -m64 -I"c:/opt/R-CURR~1/include" -DNDEBUG    -I"c:/opt/R-library/Rcpp/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
g++ -m64 -I"c:/opt/R-CURR~1/include" -DNDEBUG    -I"c:/opt/R-library/Rcpp/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c rcpp_hello_world.cpp -o rcpp_hello_world.o
g++ -m64 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o mypackage.dll tmp.def RcppExports.o rcpp_hello_world.o c:/opt/R-library/Rcpp/lib/x64/libRcpp.a -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib/x64 -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib -Lc:/opt/R-CURR~1/bin/x64 -lR
installing to c:/opt/R-library/mypackage/libs/x64
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
Warning: C:/Users/deddelbuettel/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpaiaZVk/R.INSTALL65481db46d2b/mypackage/man/mypackage-package.Rd:30: All text must be in a section
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
*** arch - i386
*** arch - x64
* DONE (mypackage)
R>
```

after which we can load and run it:

```
R> library(mypackage)
R> rcpp_hello_world()
[[1]]
[1] "foo" "bar"

[[2]]
[1] 0 1

R>
```

and finally remove it as it has no real use case besides demonstrating these mechanics:

```
R> remove.packages("mypackage")
Removing package from ‘c:/opt/R-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
R>
```

Comment: Yes, I did it. Actually, I forgot to say that I ran every piece of chapter's, and the error showed by R follows from the command rcpp_hello_world() and I was thinking that the problem might result from these two pieces of commands that I sent here.
Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Go to the terminal:

```
R CMD build mypackage
R CMD check mypackage_1.0.tar.gz
R CMD install mypackage
```

and in R:

```
library(mypackage)
rcpp_hello_world()
[[1]]
[1] "foo" "bar"

[[2]]
[1] 0 1
```

Now, I don't understand where to use the code written in "Listing 5.4", Do I need to write it or this is created automatically?